Need Engineering Drawings for Shimano Hyperglide
I am designing an adapter to fit a on the freehub of a Shimano Hyperglide. Is there anywhere I could find specifications for the dimensions or Solidworks models/drawings?

It is not difficult to draw up a UG spline.
You need to know (I.E. measure from a hub)

outer diameter (tops of splines)

inner diameter (in the valleys)

spline width

length of freehub body contact area (widely published: note 7spd, 8/9/10 spd, road 11spd are most common variants).


There are 9 equal splines for the UG system and the sprocket can fit on in any of the 9 orientations (9fold rotational symmetry) and can also be flipped over.
It is enough information to make a drawing.
HG freehubs accept UG sprockets.
HG sprockets and freehubs are keyed so the sprockets will only fit in one orientaton. This is to aid indexed shifting. It is achieved by making one of the nine splines narrower and the adjacent valley wider. You probably do not need to implement this in your design and would be better off designing your adaptor around the UG specification.
Share your design drawing for future use please.
